# Chromecast - how to stretch a video

Tags: java, android, casting, video-streaming, chromecast

I've recently began using the Chromecast API.
I'm loading a m3u8 file, works perfectly. The only problem is that the video is not stretched.

This is how I built the MediaInfo:

```
      MediaInfo m =
                    new MediaInfo.Builder("http://selevision9877-i.akamaihd.net/hls/live/219121/98773/1.m3u8")
                            .setContentType("video/mp4")
                            .setStreamType(MediaInfo.STREAM_TYPE_LIVE)
                            .build();
```

Is there any way to force the chromecast to take up the whole TV?
Currently it looks very weird, as there are 2 black bars left and right.

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Based on this [thread](http://www.tested.com/tech/set-top-boxes/457036-testing-google-chromecast/forums/?p=last) the chromecast will automatically scale the aspect ratio of your window to fill up your TV screen, adding black bars on the sides to avoid stretching. Example of this is a full-screen resolution of 1440x900 looked good on a large 1080p TV, but streaming from a 2560x1600 monitor at full-screen made the text unreadable on 70" TV.

Comment: Thanks for the info! The problem I see is that the video provided is in a low resolution/aspect ratio. But playing it in the normal Android MediaPlayer will stretch the video and fullscreen is possible, however the chromecast does not do so. 

I found an app called LocalCast, which allows the user to zoom in into the video, which does not solve my problem but at least makes it more bearable. Is there any way to do this myself in my app?

Comment: You can try/see the problem yourself when you go to [HlsPlayer](http://hlsplayer.net) and enter the video url from the post